# How to create friends and status updates using App engine

Tags: java, android

Hi guys i posted a question earlier related to this topic but i believe the question was to broad. So this time i will try to be more specific.

I would like to use Google's AppEngine to create a social networking environment for my app.

For example, it will allow a user to log in, see friends status, and their will be an activity where the user can see friends list and click a friends to load the users profile.

So basically i would like to know what should the implementation for this look like?

Such as using App Engine, Amazon S3 services, etc

**So here are my main two questions:**
how would i load a users friends list when they click the "Friends" activity?

how would i load the users current friends latest statuses?

Comment: Also how would i manage who is friends with who?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an API for your site on App Engine.

You then consume that API in your Android app.

For logins, ask users their email/username or password. You send that to your API and have it return a token associated to the user. Use that token to query the API for the user's friends status, list, etc.

Save the token in the SharedPreferences of your Android app. You check the SharedPreferences to know if the user is logged in or not.